# Mercurial pager extension

Tags: mercurial

Mercurial's pager extension doesn't use the pager for `hg status`, is this a bug?

Also, when using `hg glog -p`, the pager is used, but this doesn't conform to the [guide](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PagerExtension): "If no pager is set, the pager extension uses the environment variable `$PAGER`. If neither `pager.pager`, nor `$PAGER` is set, no pager is used." I have no `$PAGER` set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see `hg help pager`:

```
pager extension - browse command output with an external pager
[...]
Below is the default list of commands to be paged:

  [pager]
  attend = annotate, cat, diff, export, glog, log, qdiff

Setting pager.attend to an empty value will cause all commands to be paged.
[...]
```

So it's documented behavior: the status command is not paged by default.

Comment: +1, this solved my problem: None of my aliased commands were being paged, when the same command typed out manually would be paged.  So i set `attend = `, and now everything is paged.